# Write array to file by columns

Tags: arrays, file, io, fortran90

Is there a way to write columns to a file one by one? For example, I would like to write:

```
 write(1,*) 1
 write(1,*) 2
```

And then write (possibly in another subroutine)

```
 write(1,*) 3
 write(1,*) 4
```

in such a way that will produce an output file in the format:

```
 1   3
 2   4
```

without combining the arrays (e.g.)

```
 write(1,*) 1,3
 write(1,*) 2,4
```

I'm thinking that there may be a way to move the "pointer" (of file location) back to the beginning and add spaces or something, but I really have no idea if this is possible. Any help is greatly appreciated!

So far, this is my attempt to make a subroutine to make this work:

```
  subroutine writeArrayToNthColumn(arr,u,n)
    implicit none
    real(dpn),dimension(:),intent(in),target :: arr
    real(dpn),dimension(:),pointer :: parr
    integer,intent(in) :: u,n
    integer :: i,s
    s = size(arr)
    allocate(parr(s))
    parr = arr
    rewind(u)
    if (n.eq.1) then
      do i=1,s
        write(u,'(1F20.10)') parr(i)
      enddo
    else
      do i=1,s
        write(u,'(1F40.10)') parr(i)
      enddo
    endif
  end subroutine
```

But upon calling the subroutine a second time, the first column is deleted..

Comment: Yes, you could do that but it would be far easier to marshal your data inside your program and write it out row-by-row.  If you insist, then show us some code which demonstrates your best guess about how to achieve your objective.  If the code defeats you, then some pseudocode would be entirely satisfactory.

Comment: I just found the rewind() intrinsic, I'm thinking maybe implement rewind and then position the next column past the previous ones. I'm not sure if this will rewrite the entire line though. I'm going to check it out now..

Comment: rewind will typically erase everything after whatever you write.  To do what you want you would need to open the file direct access and convert all your output to strings, writing individual characters to specific byte positions in the file.

Comment: rewind() does not erase everything after whatever has been written, and converting all of the output to strings does not seem like an elegant solution..

Comment: direct access is a horribly ugly solution (to this problem), that's why I made it a comment instead of posting as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments above from George, and High Performance Mark are exactly right.  I'm posting this as an answer, because it has source code, but it should be considered an extended comment, whose only purpose is to demonstrate how right they are.

You **can** do this, in a sense, although **under no circumstances should you do so**.  Moving around within a file - a so called [seek](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/fseek.html) - is an incredibly expensive operation.  On a local hard drive, this can take 10-20 milliseconds or so per operation (eg, in this case, per entry); if you are using a large shared system it can be much larger than that.

Moving things around in memory, however, is much less expensive.  A well-tuned [transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) function will do most of the moving around in cache, with operation that take a few nanoseconds; the data will get batched into and from main memory in fewer operations which each take ~100ns or so.  Even a seek on a modern SSD will take something like dozens of microseconds.

In other words, there is no situation in which doing the transpose in your file I/O will be *less* than **hundreds of times slower** than doing the transpose in memory (and then back if needed).  You still have to do the file/IO in the end, but if you are writing out in one batch, this is much faster.

So let's try some examples in Fortran, since that's the language of this question.  Fortran, sensibly, makes this somewhat harder by making it difficult to access file locations directly, and even to explicitly output in carriage returns; I've used [direct-access IO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_95_language_features#Direct-access_files) here and hard-coded in a non-portable way of doing the carriage returns.

Here's doing the transpose in your I/O:

```
program badiotxt

    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: asize = 200
    integer, dimension(asize, asize) :: a
    integer :: i, j
    integer :: record

    forall (i=1:asize, j=1:asize)
        a(i,j) = (i-1)*asize+j
    end forall

    open(unit=7,file="bad.txt", status="new", access="direct", &
         form="formatted", action="write", recl=10)

    do j=1,asize
        do i=1,asize-1
            record=(j-1)*asize+i
            write(7, rec=record, fmt="(2X,I7,1X)") a(i,j)
        enddo
    enddo
    i = asize
    do j=1,asize
        record=(j-1)*asize+i
        write(7, rec=record, fmt="(1X,I7,A1,A1)") a(i,j), char(13), char(10)
    enddo

    close(7)

end program badiotxt
```

and here's one done by transposing the array:

```
program goodiotxt

    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: asize = 200
    integer, dimension(asize, asize) :: a
    integer :: i, j
    integer :: record

    forall (i=1:asize, j=1:asize)
        a(i,j) = (i-1)*asize+j
    end forall

    open(unit=7,file="good.txt", status="new",  &
         form="formatted", action="write")

    a = transpose(a)

    do i=1,asize
        write(7,fmt="(1X,200(2X,I7))") (a(i,j), j=1,asize)
    enddo

    a = transpose(a)

    close(7)

end program goodiotxt
```

Note that the good version is cleaner code, and that these are not large arrays by any stretch.  The resulting times are:

- Transpose in memory: 0.05s
- Transpose on disk: 1.70s
- Slowdown: 34x

Comment: Hi Jon , I agree that this doesn't technically answer my question, but I feel that it is still the right solution to look for alternatives to overuse moving around in a file, it's just slow and not the right approach. I was trying to make my IO a bit more dynamic but decided that hard-coding some things is best, it wasn't too much work. Thank you for your well-experienced answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've a bit more time now than when I first commented on this question.  This is, however, an extended comment rather than a full-blown answer.

Even IF (that's a big if) I had to write a data file column-by-column I wouldn't use direct access IO as @Jonathan Dursi's answer proposes.  That (direct access IO) is for situations where it is difficult to predict, at the time the code is written, the ordering of writes to a file.  In OP's case the ordering of writes seems to be entirely predictable.

I would:

1. Write column 1, element-by-element, to a file.

2.1 Open a second file for writing, and the first file for reading.

2.2 Read the first line from the first file, write it to the second file and append the first element of the next column.

2.3 Repeat 2.2 until I got to the end of the column/file.

2.4 Close the second file (which now contains columns 1 and 2) and the first file.

3.1 Open the second file for reading, and perform a destructive open on the first file for writing.

... by now you should have got the picture.

Comment: That might actually be a better "solution" technically. Although the performance doesn't sound like it would be great, I appreciate the alternative, Mark.