# Fortran: add column to file (i.e. skip a varying amount of horizontal spaces)

Tags: format, fortran, output, fortran90

I'm a bloody beginner to Fortran (f90) and some apparently easy problems turn out to cause severe headaches...Thanks for helping me with this one:

My code runs through a loop, processes data and writes them into a file. I'd like to have those data written in columns of the same file until the looping is finished.

```
OPEN (unit=11,file=filename // '.csv')
WRITE(11,'(i4,A1,f10.6)') NUM4 , tab, NUMfloat10_6
CLOSE(11)
```

This code works fine for the saving of a single dataset. 
"tab" is defined as char(9); filename is specified by the user at the beginning of the script.

When in loop-mode I'd like to add another tab as "A1" and another NUMfloar10_6 ("f10.6"). However, I can't so something like this:

```
OPEN (unit=11,file=filename // '.csv')
WRITE(11,'(Tk,i4,A1,f10.6)') NUM4 , tab, NUMfloat10_6
CLOSE(11)
```

with k defined as an integer, increasing with number of loop * 15.

How do you I solve that problem? How do I "add" columns to a file without knowing how many spaces to skip?

Comment: you can't just open a file and append to it column-wise, you'll either have to read in the file line-by-line, append data, write the line, or use formatted direct mode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834138/write-array-to-file-by-columns#comment36674594_23834138

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you use ifort, just add brackets `<k>`

```
  k = 2
  WRITE(*,'(T<k>,A)'), "Hello World!"

  k = 6
  WRITE(*,'(T<k>,A)'), "Hello World!"

  k = 16
  WRITE(*,'(T<k>,A)'), "Hello World!"
```

produces:

```
 Hello World!
     Hello World!
               Hello World!
```

Comment: I compiled with [ifort](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-mac/GUID-DEAE9C30-1001-49DF-AF4E-0BD5802C699F.htm), check example at the end of page

Comment: Note the description of that feature is in green.  It is an extension.  If you add /stand (or -stand) to your command line ifort should complain.

Comment: ok, updated answer. Thanks I haven't know about meaning of "green"