# Fortran: Add column per column to file

Tags: fortran, output, multiple-columns, fortran90

The code consists of a do-loop and creates arrays of data as long as running. I need these arrays added to a file as new columns.

The first column is fixed (wavelengths) and the second is generated within the first run:

```
OPEN (unit=11,file=filename // '.csv')  
WRITE(11,'(i4,A1,f10.6)') (lambda(ii),tab,resv(ii), ii=1,nw)
CLOSE(11)
```

lambda are the wavelengths (4 digits), tab is declared as char(9) and resv are my data (floating). The array consists of `nw=2000` items.

First time running the script gives me a nice output which I can load into MS Excel as .csv
However, the script is to return to the beginning of the loop, calculate new data and store the changed "resv" items into a new column.

But when I go like

```
WRITE(11,'(T17,i4,A1,f10.6)') (lambda(ii),tab,resv(ii), ii=1,nw)
```

the new data is indeed stored into column 17, but all the data before is being removed!
So how can I tell Fortran to "add" a new column?

Comment: You can't *edit* the file from a program.  Rename the file with the old data, read the old file and write out the new file with the old and new data.  When you've finished, delete the old file.

Comment: this seems to be too similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157423/fortran-add-column-to-file-i-e-skip-a-varying-amount-of-horizontal-spaces, please update/refine the original question

Comment: Sure it is similar, there are two problems for the same code. The answer to the last question was necessary to even get here. but it's not the final solution. This is my actual problem.

Comment: @cup: Same problem there. When I read the old data, how do I tell fortran it should use two new columns for that?

Comment: You simply can not write to new "columns" in an existing file. Not with fortran or any other language. You must either re-write the entire file, or initialize the file with placeholder blanks and use direct access. see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834138/write-array-to-file-by-columns#comment36674594_23834138

Comment: Thanks, georgte: The link was very useful! I solved the problem by transposing my matrix and storing variables line by line which is way easier than column by column!

Answer (score 0):

Try a variant of this.  Have a look at the code in addcolumn.  The restriction is that your line can't be more than 1024 characters long.  You can increase the size of the array to suit your needs.

```
  module mod_helper
     integer, parameter:: AMAX = 10
     integer, dimension(AMAX):: coldata
     integer:: revision
  contains
     subroutine init
        revision = 0
        do ii = 1, AMAX
           coldata(ii) = ii
        end do
     end subroutine init

     subroutine increment(howmuch)
        integer, intent(in):: howmuch
        coldata = coldata + howmuch
     end subroutine

     subroutine addcolumn(csvname)
        character*(*), intent(in) csvname
        integer(kind=2):: status
        integer:: prevlen
        character(1024):: prev, oldname, newname
        integer, parameter:: oldfile = 20, newfile = 30

        write(oldname, "(A,I3.3,'.csv')") csvname, revision
        revision = revision + 1
        write(newname, "(A,I3.3,'.csv')") csvname, revision
        if (revision .gt. 1) then
            ! Open the old file
            open(oldfile, file=oldname, access="sequential", status="old")
        end if
        open(newfile, file=newname, access="sequential", status="new", action="write")
        prev = ' '
        do ii = 1, AMAX
            if (revision .gt. 1) then
                ! read previous contents as a string
                read(oldfile, "(A)") prev
                prevlen = len(trim(prev))
            else
                prevlen = 1
            end if
            ! write previous and new contents
            write(newfile, "(A, I4, ',')") prev(1:prevlen), coldata(ii)
        end do
        ! delete the previous file
        if (revision .gt. 1) close(oldfile, status='delete')
        close(newfile)
     end subroutine
  end module

  program main
     use mod_helper

     call init
     call addcolumn('col')
     call increment(1)
     call addcolumn('col')
     call increment(20)
     call addcolumn('col')
  end program
```